# Linked-list in C without typedefs and globals?

Tags: c, linked-list

I took [RosettaCode's](https://www.rosettacode.org/wiki/Singly-linked_list/Element_definition#C) [implementation](https://www.rosettacode.org/wiki/Singly-linked_list/Element_insertion#C) and tried to create something useable (editing their wiki as I go to give-back):

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct elem {
  long data;
  struct elem *next;
};
```

##### Insert

```c
struct elem *addToList(struct elem *node, long num) {
  struct elem *iter, *temp;

  if (node == NULL) {
    node = (struct elem *)malloc(sizeof(struct elem *));
    node->data = num;
    node->next = NULL;
  } else {
    iter = node;

    while (iter->next != NULL) {
      iter = iter->next;
    }

    temp = (struct elem *)malloc(sizeof(struct elem *));
    temp->data = num;
    temp->next = NULL;

    iter->next = temp;
  }
  return node;
}
```

##### Delete

```c
struct elem *deleteFromList(struct elem *node, size_t pos) {
  size_t i = 1;
  struct elem *temp, *iter;

  if (node != NULL) {
    iter = node;

    if (pos == 1) {
      node = node->next;
      iter->next = NULL;
      free(iter);
    }

    else {
      while (i++ != pos - 1)
        iter = iter->next;
      temp = iter->next;
      iter->next = temp->next;
      temp->next = NULL;
      free(temp);
    }
  }
  return node;
}
```

##### Print

```c
void printList(struct elem *node) {
  struct elem *iter;
  puts("List contains following elements : \n");

  for (iter = node; iter != NULL; iter = iter->next) {
    printf("%ld ", iter->data);
    // access data, e.g. with iter->data
  }
}
```

---

ASans crashes @ `node->next = NULL` of `addToList` with `heap-buffer-overflow`.

What do you think of this implementation? - How can it be improved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Special cases are bad. Eliminate them if possible.

   Specifically, an empty list is not all that special.

   Is an empty list any more special than an unexpectedly short list?
2. Extract useful functions if possible. Appending consists of finding the end, and prepending to it, two useful functions.
3. Do you write C or C++?

   In C, casting the result of `malloc()` is heavily frowned upon, as it means useless repetition.
4. Avoid `sizeof(TYPE)`.

   One easily gets it wrong (as you do!!), it haphazardly sprinkles unchecked duplicate information (the type) about which has to be manually verified, and it impedes refactoring.

   Use `sizeof *target` instead, which properly couples size and use.
5. Unless you are restricted to strict C90 or earlier, you can mix declarations and instructions. Doing so limits scope and simplifies code.
6. A pointer has a truth-value, no need to compare to a null pointer constant.
7. Use concise but precise names.

   If you add to a list, *where* do you add it?

   - To every element.
   - Prepended.
   - Appended.
   - Behind a given node / index / value.
   - Randomly.
   - Arbitrarily.
   - ...
8. C does not have namespaces, thus the use of prefixes to avoid collisions. Consider an appropriate one.
9. Dynamic allocation can fail. Deal with it.

Applying it to the first function:

```
struct elem **list_end(struct elem **p) {
    assert(p);
    while (*p)
        p = &p[0]->next;
    return p;
}
struct elem **list_prepend(struct elem **p, long v) {
    assert(p);
    struct elem *x = malloc(sizeof *x);
    if (!x)
        return NULL; /* or abort(); */
    x->data = v;
    x->next = *p;
    *p = x;
    return &x->next;
}
struct elem **list_append(struct elem **p, long v) {
    return list_prepend(list_end(p), v);
}
```

Comment: Very nice, I would even use `void append(struct elem **root, long num) {`

Comment: Thanks, much cleaner. In terms of your `abort`, should that be `exit(ENOMEM)`? - Or should I set errno and check if everywhere? - Maybe return `NULL` after setting errno? - Also is your append `O(n)`? - Actually I guess I just pass it the previous last pointer and it'll be `O(1)`…

Comment: @AT These routines should act like `malloc()` on out-of-memory.  `malloc()` did not abort or exit, it returned an error indication for the caller to decide.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica There is a reason some use a replacement `abort()`-ing on OOM.

Comment: @Deduplicator Hmm, I think I'm doing something wrong with the instantiation: https://ideone.com/miu03S - In my real code it's only ever adding one or two elements to the linked-list, in this example code (63 lines) it's not storing any elements…

Answer (score 1):

**O(n) vs. O(1) Append**

Rather than O(n) to append to the linked list, consider a speedy O(1) alternative.

Let `struct elem *node` point to the end of the list and that `node->next` point to the start.

Adding to the front or back of the list is then O(1).

Complete walking of the list is not detected by `NULL`, but by the iterator  == end_of_list.

Comment: Yesterday I did modify @Deduplicator's answer with `return insert;` and hten I used that later, so that should give O(1)

Comment: @AT A bit unclear by "modify @Deduplicator's answer with return insert;", yet that sounds like you also changed the functionality of the `append()` into `preappend()`.

Comment: you can also insert before and after, or delete after a given node with O(1). You can consider this part of the appeal of linked lists.